# No logro mostrar mis datos almacenados en mi base de datos usando django smart selects

Tags: django, django-smart-selects

estoy en un proyecto django en el cual tengo tres modelos, Provincia, Departamento y Localidad. Investigando un poco me decidí a usar **django-smart-select** para poder relacionarlos, para así cuando selecciono un provincia que solo me muestre los departamentos afectados, como así también con las localidades. Desde el admin de django me anda perfecto ahora que instale el django-smart-select, pero desde mi formulario no se como realizar esto mismo. Supongo que mi error esta en como esta definido mi formulario, pero no logro dar con una solución (soy novato aún en desarrollo web).

Estos son los modelos:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

    class Provincia(models.Model):
        provincia_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        provincia = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        fecha_alta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'provincia'
            verbose_name = 'Provincia'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Provincias'
            ordering = ['provincia_id']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.provincia
    
    
    class Departamento(models.Model):
        departamento_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        provincia_id = models.ForeignKey(Provincia, db_column='provincia_id', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        departamento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        fecha_alta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'Departamento'
            verbose_name = 'Departamento'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Departamentos'
            ordering = ['departamento_id']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.departamento
    
    
    class Localidad(models.Model):
        localidad_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)    
        #departamento_id = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, db_column='departamento_id', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        provincia_id = models.ForeignKey(Provincia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        dpto = ChainedForeignKey(
            "Departamento",
            chained_field="provincia_id",
            chained_model_field="provincia_id",
            show_all=False,
            auto_choose=True,
        )
        localidad = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        codigo_postal = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
        fecha_alta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'localidad'
            verbose_name = 'Localidad'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Localidades'
            ordering = ['localidad_id']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.localidad
```

Este el formulario:

```
class RegistroPersonaJuridica(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(label=('Nombre'), max_length=120, required=True)#Se guardara en el campo RazonSocial de persona
    email = forms.EmailField(label=('Email'), required=False)
    cod_area = forms.CharField(label=('Codigo de Area'), max_length=6, required=False)
    nro_tel = forms.CharField(label=('Número de Telefono'), max_length=15, required=False)
    tel_tipo = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=('Tipo'), queryset=Telefono_tipo.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 2]), required=False)
    tel_clasif = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=('Clasif.'), queryset=Telefono_clasificacion.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 2]), required=False)    
    provincia = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=('Provincia'), queryset=Provincia.objects.all().order_by('provincia'), required=True)
    departamento = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=('Departamento'), queryset=Departamento.objects.all().order_by('departamento'), required=True)
    localidad = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=('Localidad'), queryset=Localidad.objects.all().order_by('localidad'), required=True)
    calle = forms.CharField(label=('Direccion'), max_length=50, required=True)
    nro_puerta = forms.IntegerField(label=('N° puerta'), required=True)
    activa = forms.BooleanField(initial= True, required=False)
    envios = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Esta es la view:

```
def nuevo_registro_per_juridica(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroPersonaJuridica(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            '''
             Desarrollo de guardado.
            '''
        else:
            for msg in form.errors:
                messages.error(request, form.errors[msg])
            return render(request, 'persona/registro_per_juridica.html', {'form':form})

        messages.success(request, f"bien echo!")    
        return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = RegistroPersonaJuridica()
        for msg in form.errors:
            messages.error(request, form.errors[msg])
    return render(request, 'persona/registro_per_juridica.html', {'form':form})
```

Este es el html:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="mt-2" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
</form>
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias por sus respuestas!

Me encuentro utilizando las siguientes versiones:

Django==3.1.1

django-smart-selects==1.5.9

python 3

Answer (score 0):

Mediante los DevTools de Chrome asegurate que este cargando los archivos:

```
smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js
smart-selects/admin/js/bindfields.js
```

Estos archivos son requeridos para que funcione la selección dinámica.

Answer (score 0):

a mí me pasaba lo mismo. La solución que encontré es simple. Al archivo settings.py añadí esto: USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True.
Anteriormente tenía esto también: JQUERY_URL = False, pero no me funcionaba el segundo select, así que borré esto último y todo se solucionó.